# Is there alternative of "similar to" on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to find string using regular expression on AgensGraph.

```
agens=# create (:v1{value:'text'});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# match (n:v1) where n.value similar to 't%' return n;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "similar"
LINE 1: match (n:v1) where n.value similar to 't%' return n;
                                   ^
```

But, there is an error on it.

Is there alternative of "similar to" on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Use operator "=~" for search using regex patten.

```
agens=# match (n:v1) where n.value =~ 't*' return n;
            n             
--------------------------
 v1[3.1]{"value": "text"}
(1 row)
```